# How can I run nginx on project files on windows?

Tags: html, windows, powershell, nginx, static-content

I am trying to run NGINX locally on my windows computer.

```
I installed the pkg from https://nginx.org/en/download.html & un zipped it to my c drive and tried to run nginx -v and i got this err
```

**nginx : The term 'nginx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nginx -v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nginx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

```
I am using html css and js and like to use nginx for static content. 

I really dont understand what I am doing wrong..
```

Comment: If `nginx.exe` is located in the _current directory_, `cmd.exe` allows you to call it _by name only_ - `nginx .exe` or `nginx ` - or, with an explicit path, `.\nginx`; **In PowerShell, _only_ `.\nginx` (or `./nginx`) works**, because, by security-minded design, PowerShell requires you to signal the intent to invoke an executable located in the _current_ directory explicitly.

Comment: The previous comment summarizes the information in the first linked duplicate. If your problem is instead related to expecting `nginx` to be in `$env:PATH`, see the second duplicate.